# Javascript - Cannot call method 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, split

I have a javascript error that occurs on my site, Im pretty sure I know why, but I dont know how to fix it!

here's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null
```

Here's my JS code:

```
$(function(e) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("login") >= 0) {
        $("a#loggedInUser").html( $.cookie("login").split("|")[0] );
    }
});
```

I'm just trying to display the username stored in the "login" cookie. Now, im pretty sure the error is because the value returned sometimes isn't a string, then it doesn't have the split method, so it causes this error.

How can I fix that? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note: javascript != jquery. Tag fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can do something like this to set a default if the value is null.

```
var login = $.cookie("login") || "";
$("a#loggedInUser").html(login);
```

Also, if you do that you might not need the `document.cookie.indexOf` thing.

Comment: then calling the split method on the "" default value would not cause the same error?

Comment: `""` is a String object and therefore has the `split` method.

`"".split("|")` => `[ '' ]`
`"".split("|")[0]` => `''` (empty string)

Comment: Try opening up your web console or the firebug console and running these yourself. It's the quickest way to know if they will work!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the case that `$.cookie("login")` is not returning a valid string.  I think the problem is that it's possible that: `document.cookie.indexOf("login") >= 0` is true but `$.cookie("login")` is still `null` or `undefined`.  It makes sense to use the same check e.g.:

```
$(function(e) {
    var cookie = $.cookie("login");
    if(cookie) {
        $("a#loggedInUser").html( cookie.split("|")[0] );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the cookie. This way you validate two things at once.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("login") >= 0 && $.cookie("login").length) {
    $("a#loggedInUser").html( $.cookie("login").split("|")[0] );
}
```